# Terraform add to list from defaults.tfvars

Tags: terraform

I am trying to extend a declared variable list, is this possible using terraforms?

Declare a variable as such:

```
variable "nat_rules" {
  type = list(object({
    name          = string
    protocol      = string
    frontend_port = number
    backend_port  = number
  }))
}
```

Then in the default.tfvars I'd like to set it to the default NAT list:

```
nat_rules = [
    {
        name = "Admin"
        protocol      = "Tcp"
        frontend_port = 11389
        backend_port  = 3389
    }, {
        name = "HTTP"
        protocol      = "Tcp"
        frontend_port = 80
        backend_port  = 80
    }, {
        name = "HTTPs"
        protocol      = "Tcp"
        frontend_port = 443
        backend_port  = 443
    }]
```

Now in the environment override tfvars file, I'd like to add a 4th item to this lift from the defaults. Something like the one below, but that did not work.

```
nat_rules = concat(var.nat_rules,[{
    name = "SSH"
    protocol      = "Tcp"
    frontend_port = 22
    backend_port  = 22
}])
```

**Edit:** didn't work = got this error:

```
 Error: Function calls not allowed
│
│   on environments/prod_ci/prod_ci.tfvars line 98:
│   98: nat_rules = concat(var.nat_rules,[{
│   99:     name = "SSH"
│  100:     protocol      = "Tcp"
│  101:     frontend_port = 22
│  102:     backend_port  = 22
│  103: }])
│
│ Functions may not be called here.
╵
```

Basically, I am hoping for something like the += operator from other languages. The idea would be to be able to define a big list of common rules and then add any additional ones as needed for prod / test / dev without having to repeat the whole list just to add 1 extra entry.

Comment: "but that did not work" - what does it mean? Any errors?

Comment: I don't think you can do that. You can however define a value in `terraform.tfvars` which has everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that , you cannot call a function in .tfvars ,

rather pass the var  in a tfvars file like such

```
additional_rules = [{
name = "SSH"
protocol      = "Tcp"
frontend_port = 22
backend_port  = 22
}]
```

```
variable "additional_rules" {
  type = list(object({
    name          = string
    protocol      = string
    frontend_port = number
    backend_port  = number
  }))
}
```

and then in a locals.tf file you can do the concatenation like such :

```
locals{ 
  default_rules =  [
{
    name = "Admin"
    protocol      = "Tcp"
    frontend_port = 11389
    backend_port  = 3389
}, {
    name = "HTTP"
    protocol      = "Tcp"
    frontend_port = 80
    backend_port  = 80
}, {
    name = "HTTPs"
    protocol      = "Tcp"
    frontend_port = 443
    backend_port  = 443
}]

  rules = concat(local.default_rules, var.additional_rules)
}
```